# iOS - Can't pass UIColor * as a parameter?

Tags: ios, draw, uicolor

I want to pass UIColor * as a parameter, but my program keeps crashing at [paramColour set]. 
I know I can pass in a string and select the UIColor from there but I'm just wondering why this doesn't work. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (void) drawRooftopAtTopPointof:(CGPoint)paramTopPoint
                      colour:(UIColor *)paramColour
                    lineJoin:(CGLineJoin)paramLineJoin{

/* Set the color that we want to use to draw the line */
[paramColour set];

/* Get the current graphics context */
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

/* Set the line join */
CGContextSetLineJoin(currentContext,
                     paramLineJoin);

/* Set the width for the lines */
CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext,
                      3.0f);

/* Start the line at this point */
CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext,
                     paramTopPoint.x - 10,
                     paramTopPoint.y + 8);

/* And end it at this point */
CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext,
                        paramTopPoint.x,
                        paramTopPoint.y);

/* Extend the line to another point to
 make the rooftop */
CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext,
                        paramTopPoint.x + 10,
                        paramTopPoint.y + 8);

/* Use the context's current color to draw the lines */
CGContextStrokePath(currentContext);

/* Draw the text in the rooftop using a black color */
[[UIColor blackColor] set];

}
```

Here's my drawRect in the view that triggers this drawing function.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

for (int i=0; i < arrowsToDrawArray.count; i++)
{
    Arrow * arrowObj = [arrowsToDrawArray objectAtIndex:i];
    UIColor * colourOfArrow = [arrowObj colourOfArrow]; // colour determines whether right or wrong
    CGPoint p = [arrowObj arrowPlacement];

//    CGPoint p = [val CGPointValue]; 
    [self drawRooftopAtTopPointof:p colour:colourOfArrow lineJoin:kCGLineJoinMiter];
}
}
```

and here's the definition of Arrow class.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Arrow; 

@interface Arrow : NSObject
{
UIColor * colourOfArrow; 
CGPoint arrowPlacement; 
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIColor * colourOfArrow;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint arrowPlacement; 

@end
```

Comment: What exactly is the crash...do you have a trace?  My first guess is that the `paramColour` must somehow be `nil`; are you absolutely sure it's initialized?  If you replace `[paramColour set]` temporarily with something like `[[UIColor redColor] set]`, does the drawing code otherwise work?

Comment: try by commenting out the line "UIColor * colourOfArrow = [arrowObj colourOfArrow];" and make function call as [self drawRooftopAtTopPointof:p colour:[arrowObj colourOfArrow] lineJoin:kCGLineJoinMiter];

Comment: Hi Kevin, the paramColour isn't NIL, it's become a strange UIPlaceHolderColor pointer that I've not encountered before.The drawing works with [[UIColor redColor] set], but it's not really what I want.

Comment: Arshad, I did that, same error..

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for the help,

I decided to do it properly, with constructor and all, here's the new code. Seems to be working now.

arrow.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Arrow; 

@interface Arrow : NSObject
{
UIColor * colourOfArrow; 
CGPoint arrowPlacement; 
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIColor * colourOfArrow;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint arrowPlacement; 

+ (Arrow *) createArrowWithColour :(UIColor *)paramColour andPosition :(CGPoint)      xPosition;

@end
```

arrow.m

```
#import "Arrow.h"

@implementation Arrow
@synthesize colourOfArrow;
@synthesize arrowPlacement;

+ (Arrow *) createArrowWithColour :(UIColor *)paramColour andPosition :(CGPoint) xPosition
{
Arrow * tempArrow = [[Arrow alloc] init];
[tempArrow setColourOfArrow:paramColour];
[tempArrow setArrowPlacement:xPosition];

return tempArrow;
}

@end
```